# How to build Convolutional Bi-directional LSTM with Keras

Tags: deep-learning, theano, convolution, keras, lstm

I'm trying to build a Convolutional Bi-directional LSTM to classify DNA sequences ala this paper: [DanQ: a hybrid convolutional and recurrent deep
neural network for quantifying the function of DNA
sequences (Architecture picture on the second page)](http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2016/04/15/nar.gkw226.full.pdf)

The short version of it is to build to one-hot encode a DNA sequence:

```
 `'ATACG...' = [
[1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0],
[0,0,1,0],
...],`
```

Then feed it to a convolutional-relu-maxpooling layer to find motifs, then into a bidirectional LSTM network to learn long-distance dependancies.

The original source code is [here.](https://github.com/uci-cbcl/DanQ/blob/master/DanQ_train.py)

However, it uses an outdated version of Keras and includes a dependency on Seya, which is what I'd like to avoid doing. Here is my first attempt at building the model:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(500,4))
convo_1 = Convolution1D(320, border_mode='valid',filter_length=26, activation="relu", subsample_length=1)(inputs)
maxpool_1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_length=13, stride=13)(convo_1)
drop_1 = Dropout(0.2)(maxpool_1)
l_lstm = LSTM(320, return_sequences = True, go_backwards= False)(drop_1)
r_lstm = LSTM(320, return_sequences = True, go_backwards= True)(drop_1)
merged = merge([l_lstm, r_lstm], mode='sum')
drop_2 = Dropout(0.5)(merged)
flat = Flatten()(drop_2)
dense_1 = Dense(320, activation='relu')(flat)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')(dense_1)

model = Model(inputs, out)
print ('compiling model')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=sc_local_dir+"DanQ_bestmodel.hdf5", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, verbose=1)
```

Unfortunately, the loss remained nearly constant during training, and the accuracy stayed constant as well. This leads me to believe that I have set the model up incorrectly, or that **1-dimensional convolution** is useless on this kind of input. So i attempted to make switch to **2D convolution**:

```
    inputs = Input(shape=(1, 500,4))
convo_1 = Convolution2D(320, nb_row=15, nb_col=4, init='glorot_uniform', \
                       activation='relu', border_mode='same')(inputs)
maxpool_1 = MaxPooling2D((15, 4))(convo_1)
flat_1 = Flatten()(maxpool_1)
drop_1 = Dropout(0.2)(flat_1)
l_lstm = LSTM(320, return_sequences = True, go_backwards= False)(drop_1)
r_lstm = LSTM(320, return_sequences = True, go_backwards= True)(drop_1)
merged = merge([l_lstm, r_lstm], mode='sum')
drop_2 = Dropout(0.5)(merged)
flat = Flatten()(drop_2)
dense_1 = Dense(320, activation='relu')(flat)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')(dense_1)

model = Model(inputs, out)
print ('compiling model')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=sc_local_dir+"DanQ_bestmodel.hdf5", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, verbose=1)
```

Which gives me the following error when trying to feed the flattened layer into the LSTM:

Exception: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_4: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Have I set up my 1D Convolution LSTM correctly? If so, then I likely need to upgrade to a 2D Convolution LSTM, in which case, how can I fix the input error?

Comment: I will try to help you out with this.  What is your `y` during the fit? How many classes are there for `num_classes`?  Can you post a link with the input matrices?

Comment: Can you help with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543113/how-to-use-bidirectional-lstm-and-conv1d-in-keras-shaped-not-matching