# How to use Bidirectional RNN and Conv1D in keras when shapes are not matching?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, convolution, recurrent-neural-network

I am brand new to `Deep-Learning` so I'm reading though [Deep Learning with Keras by Antonio Gulli](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1787128423) and learning a lot.  I want to start using some of the concepts. I want to try and implement a neural network with a 1-dimensional convolutional layer that feeds into a bidirectional recurrent layer (like the paper below).  All the tutorials or code snippets I've encountered do not implement anything remotely similar to this (e.g. image recognition) or use an older version of `keras` with different functions and usage.

---

**What I'm trying to do is a variation of [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4914104/):**

(1) convert DNA sequences to `one-hot encoding` vectors; **✓**

(2) use a 1 dimensional convolutional neural network; **✓**

(3) with max pooling; **✓**

(4) send the output to a `bidirectional RNN`;   **ⓧ**

(5) classify the input;

---

I cannot figure out how to get the shapes to match up on the `Bidirectional RNN`.  I can't even get an ordinary `RNN` to work at this stage.  **How can I restructure the incoming layers to work with a Bidirectional RNN?**

Note:
The original code came from https://github.com/uci-cbcl/DanQ/blob/master/DanQ_train.py but I simplified the output layer to just do binary classification.  This processed was described (kind of) in https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3322 but I cannot get it to work with the updated `keras`.  The original code (and the 2nd link) work on a very large dataset so I am generating some fake data to illustrate the concept. They are also using an older version of `keras` where key functionality changes have been made since then.

```
# Imports
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.layers.core import *
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, SimpleRNN, Bidirectional, Input
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.models import Model, Sequential

# Set up TensorFlow backend
K = tf.keras.backend
K.set_session(tf.Session())
np.random.seed(0) # For keras?

# Constants
NUMBER_OF_POSITIONS = 40
NUMBER_OF_CLASSES = 2
NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES_IN_EACH_CLASS = 25

# Generate sequences
https://pastebin.com/GvfLQte2

# Build model
# ===========
# Input Layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(NUMBER_OF_POSITIONS,4))
# Hidden Layers
y = Conv1D(100, 10, strides=1, activation="relu", )(input_layer)
y = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides=5)(y)
y = Flatten()(y)
y = Bidirectional(SimpleRNN(100, return_sequences = True, activation="tanh", ))(y)
y = Flatten()(y)
y = Dense(100, activation='relu')(y)
# Output layer
output_layer = Dense(NUMBER_OF_CLASSES, activation="softmax")(y)

model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", )
model.summary()


# ~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/layers/recurrent.py in build(self, input_shape)
#    1049     input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list()
#    1050     batch_size = input_shape[0] if self.stateful else None
# -> 1051     self.input_dim = input_shape[2]
#    1052     self.input_spec[0] = InputSpec(shape=(batch_size, None, self.input_dim))
#    1053 

# IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to restructure anything at all to get the output of a Conv1D layer into an LSTM layer.

So, the problem is simply the presence of the `Flatten` layer, which destroys the shape.

These are the shapes used by Conv1D and LSTM:

- Conv1D: `(batch, length, channels)`
- LSTM: `(batch, timeSteps, features)`

Length is the same as timeSteps, and channels is the same as features.

Using the `Bidirectional` wrapper won't change a thing either. It will only duplicate your output features.

---

### Classifying.

If you're going to classify the entire sequence as a whole, your last LSTM must use `return_sequences=False`. (Or you may use some flatten + dense instead after)

If you're going to classify each step of the sequence, all your LSTMs should have `return_sequences=True`. You should not flatten the data after them.

Comment: Ok I think I understand.  When I have `return_sequences = True` it only works if I remove the `Flatten` step after the `Dropout` but if I have `return_sequences = False` I have to use `Flatten` for it to compile.  This was insanely helpful.  Thanks a lot (especially the Clairifying bit at the end).  It makes the original implementation make more sense to me.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to change the output layer dimensions? https://i.imgur.com/9RlgZPX.png It is `(None, None, 2) ` but my `Y` is `(n_samples, m_classes)`

Comment: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (50, 2)`

Comment: So, by your `Y`, you're not classifying each step. You need either to use `return_sequences=False` in the last LSTM, or a `Flatten()` somewhere "after the LSTMs and before the last Dense".

Comment: When you say "you're not classifying each step" do you mean each convolution or each LSTM cell output (320)? [@Daniel Moller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2097240/daniel-m%C3%B6ller)

Comment: I'm talking about your data, where "time step" = "sequence length" = "frames in a video" = "samples in an audio file", etc. --- You're classifying the entire sequence at once, you're not classifying each frame/time step of your data.

Comment: I'm talking about your data, where "time step" = "sequence length" = "frames in a video" = "samples in an audio file", etc. --- You're classifying the entire sequence at once, you're not classifying each frame/time step of your data.

Comment: Got it!  So in this case it would have been whatever was being fed into the LSTM being  a sequence of maxpooled filters, right?