# How to use Conv1D and Bidirectional LSTM in keras to do multiclass classification of each timestep?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, convolution, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to use a Conv1D and Bidirectional LSTM in keras (much like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543113/how-to-use-bidirectional-lstm-and-conv1d-in-keras-when-shapes-are-not-matching/47564417#47564417)) for signal processing, but doing a multiclass classification of each time step.

The problem is that even though the shapes used by Conv1D and LSTM are somewhat equivalent:

> Conv1D: (batch, length, channels)
> LSTM: (batch, timeSteps, features)

The output of the Conv1D is = (length - (kernel_size - 1)/strides), and therefore doesn't match the LSTM shape anymore, even without using MaxPooling1D and Dropout.

To be more specific, my training set X has n samples with 1000 time steps and one channel (n_samples, 1000, 1), and I used LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder so y has n samples, 1000 time steps and 5 one hot encoded classes (n_samples, 1000, 5).

Since one class is much more prevalent than the others (is actually the absence of signal), I am using loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', sample_weight_mode="temporal" and sample_weight to give a higher weight to time steps containing meaningful classes.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, strides=1, input_shape = (1000, 1), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(5, activation='softmax')))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'], sample_weight_mode="temporal")
print(model.summary())
```

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pHph.png)

When I try to fit the model I get this error message:

> Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_1 to have shape
> (None, 998, 1) but got array with shape (100, 1000, 5).

**Is there a way to make such a neural network configuration work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your convolution is cutting the tips of the sequence. Use `padding='same'` in the convolutional layers.

The message, though, seems not to fit your model. Your model clearly has 5 output features (because of `Dense(5)`), but the massage says it expects 1. Maybe this is happening because of "sparse" crossentropy. You should probably, by the format of your data, use a "categorical_crossentropy".

Comment: Thanks for the `padding='same'` part. However, I have no idea why I am getting that error message even though I have the `Dense(5)`. Now it says: "expected time_distributed_1 to have shape (None, 1000, 1) but got array with shape (100, 1000, 5)".

Comment: Isn't it because of "sparse" categorical crossentropy? I don't think you need sparse if your data has all 5 elements.

Comment: Great, that was it! Changed to "categorical_crossentropy" and it worked perfectly! I wonder when would one use "sparse_categorical_crossentropy"...

Comment: Sparse tensors try to be smaller by eliminating data that is zero. For using "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", you should probably try to use everything possible sparse in the model, and make your data sparse as well. (But I don't know how to, no experience with sparse models)

Comment: Sparse tensors try to be smaller by eliminating data that is zero. For using "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", you should probably try to use everything possible sparse in the model, and make your data sparse as well. (But I don't know how to, no experience with sparse models)

Comment: Once the shape of output is (100,1000,5), how many neurons can I consider at output? 5 neurons, 5000 neurons, or 5 neuron foreach timestep totalizing 5000?

Comment: Five "filters". A filter may be compared to a neuron. But this neuron will run the entire length.

Comment: I meant to say the output of dense layer. Filters are related to convolutional layers, right?

Comment: Oh... sorry, yes. 5 unique neurons (applied once for each slice)